# Minimal Free Resolutions

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory*, Chapter 7 p. 153-4:

> Let $(A, \mathfrak{m}, k)$ be a local ring.
>
> An exact sequence 
>   $$(*) \cdots \rightarrow L_i \xrightarrow{d_i} L_{i-1} \xrightarrow{d_{i-1}} \cdots \rightarrow L_1 \xrightarrow{d_1} L_0 \xrightarrow{\epsilon} M \rightarrow 0$$
>
> is called a *minimal (free) resolution* of $M$ if it satisfies the following three conditions
>
> (1) Each $L_i$ is a finite free $A$-module
>
> (2) $\bar{d_i} = 0$, or in other words $d_iL_i \subset\mathfrak mL_{i-1}$ for all $i$ (where $\bar{d_i}$ is the map $L_i \otimes k \rightarrow L_{i-1} \otimes k$ induced by $L_i \xrightarrow{d_i} L_{i-1}$)
>
> (3) $\bar{\epsilon}: L_0 \otimes k \rightarrow M \otimes k$ is an isomorphism.
>
> Breaking up $(*)$ into short exact sequences $0 \rightarrow K_1 \rightarrow L_0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$, $0 \rightarrow K_2 \rightarrow L_1 \rightarrow K_1 \rightarrow 0$, $...$, we have $L_0 \otimes k \xrightarrow{\sim} M \otimes k$, $L_1 \otimes k \xrightarrow{\sim} K_1 \otimes k$, $...$ Any two minimal resolutions of $M$ are isomorphic as complexes (prove this).

## Questions

1) Since the tensor product is right-exact, we see that

$$\cdots \rightarrow L_i \otimes k \xrightarrow{\bar{d_i}} L_{i-1} \otimes k \xrightarrow{\bar{d_{i-1}}} \cdots \rightarrow L_1 \otimes k \xrightarrow{\bar{d_1}} L_0 \otimes k \xrightarrow{\bar{\epsilon}} M \otimes k \rightarrow 0$$

is also exact. But by condition (2), we have $\bar{d_i} = 0$ for all $i$ so that $0 =$ image($\bar{d_1}$) = Ker($\bar{\epsilon}$) $\implies$ $\bar{\epsilon}$ is an isomorphism. Doesn't this mean that condition (3) follows from condition (2)?

2) I searched online to see what an "isomorphism" of chain complexes was but couldn’t really find anything. I’m guessing “isomorphism” means “homotopy equivalence” but I’m not really sure how to prove that. I would appreciate any hints or anything….

Comment: The tensor product is right-exact on `short` exact sequences, not on long ones.

Comment: An isomorphism of chain complexes is a family of isomorphisms between the corresponding modules of the two complexes which moreover commute with the differentials.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks for the definition. Here’s what I did: Let $\cdots L_i \xrightarrow{d_i} L_{i-1} \xrightarrow{d_{i-1}} \cdots \rightarrow L_1 \xrightarrow{d_1} L_0 \xrightarrow{\epsilon} M \rightarrow 0$ and $\cdots L’_i \xrightarrow{d’_i} L’_{i-1} \xrightarrow{d’_{i-1}} \cdots \rightarrow L’_1 \xrightarrow{d’_1} L’_0 \xrightarrow{\epsilon’} M \rightarrow 0$ be two minimal resolutions of $M$. I can see how $L_i$ and $L’_i$ must be isomorphic, but I’m having trouble showing that the diagram commutes. I’ll continue in the next comment.

Comment: @user26857 We have the s.e.s. $0 \rightarrow K_1’ \rightarrow L_0’ \xrightarrow{\epsilon'} M \rightarrow 0$ and we have a map $\epsilon: L_0 \rightarrow M$. Since $L_0$ is free and thus projective, there must exist a map $h: L_0 \rightarrow L_0’$ such that the diagram commutes. But I’m not sure if $h$ is an isomorphism. For instance, if $x, y \in L_0$ such that $x \not= y$, but if $x-y \in K_1$, then there is nothing that guarantees that $h(x) \not = h(y)$. In other words, I know that $L_i$ and $L_i’$ are isomorphic but I'm not sure if $h$ is that isomorphism.

Comment: @Artos Why don't try to define similarly a map $L_0'\to L_0$ and show they are inverse each other?

Comment: @user26857 Thanks, but I cannot see how that would help. We could define (in a similar way) $g: L_0' \rightarrow L_0$ and get $d_1g = d_1'$. This would give us $d_1'hg=d_1'$ and $d_1gh = d_1$. But we don't know if $d_1$ or $d_1'$ is injective or not...so we cannot assume that it has a left inverse, right?